# How to group by and include zero sums

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to write a query that returns sums of transactions within every category the user has created in my application.  My current query works fine but it does not display a category if no transactions have been made under that category yet.  I want my query to display every category even if the sum of everything is 0.

I looked up how to do it and was suggested to use a LEFT/RIGHT OUTER JOIN but it doesn't do what I want.

I am accessing a Microsoft Access 2007 Database via Windows C# Application. This is my current query:

```
SELECT Categories.CategoryName ,
       SUM( Transactions.TransactionCredit ) as CreditSum ,
       SUM( Transactions.TransactionDebit  ) as DebitSum  ,
       SUM( Transactions.TransactionCredit ) -
       SUM( Transactions.TransactionDebit  ) as Difference ,
       SUM( Transactions.TransactionDebit  ) /
       ( SELECT SUM(TransactionDebit)
         FROM Transactions
         WHERE AccountID = {currentAccountId}
       ) as 'Percent of Total Debit'
FROM Categories
LEFT JOIN Transactions on Categories.CategoryName = Transactions.CategoryName
WHERE Transactions.AccountID = {currentAccountId}
  AND TransactionDate >= {startDate}
  AND TransactionDate <= {endDate}
GROUP BY Categories.CategoryName
```

This is how it is coded in my c# app:

```
queries.returnQuery("SELECT Categories.CategoryName, " +
"SUM(Transactions.TransactionCredit) as CreditSum, " +
"SUM(Transactions.TransactionDebit) as DebitSum, " +
"SUM(Transactions.TransactionCredit) - SUM(Transactions.TransactionDebit) as Difference, " +
"SUM(Transactions.TransactionDebit) / (SELECT SUM(TransactionDebit) FROM Transactions WHERE AccountID = " + currentAccountID + ") as 'Percent of Total Debit' " +
"FROM Categories LEFT JOIN Transactions on Categories.CategoryName = Transactions.CategoryName " +
"WHERE Transactions.AccountID = " + currentAccountID +
(enableDateFilter ? " AND Transactions.TransactionDate >= #" + startDate + "# AND Transactions.TransactionDate <= #" + endDate + "# " : " ") +
" GROUP BY Categories.CategoryName");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I faced was that when using a JOIN you have to use conditions that compare the two tables together.  In my case, I wasn't doing that.  I was using parameters that the user chose in the c# application so I used a SUBQUERY in place of the Transactions table and got the intended results.  See my solution below:

Solution in C#:

```
queries.returnQuery("SELECT Categories.CategoryName, " +
                           "SUM(SUBQUERY.TransactionCredit) as CreditSum, " +
                           "SUM(SUBQUERY.TransactionDebit) as DebitSum, " +
                           "SUM(SUBQUERY.TransactionCredit) - SUM(SUBQUERY.TransactionDebit) as Difference " +
                           "FROM Categories LEFT JOIN " +
                               "(SELECT CategoryName, TransactionCredit, TransactionDebit FROM Transactions WHERE AccountID = " + currentAccountID + 
                               (enableDateFilter ? " AND TransactionDate >= #" + startDate + "# AND TransactionDate <= #" + endDate + "# " : " ") + 
                               ") AS SUBQUERY " + 
                           "ON Categories.CategoryName = SUBQUERY.CategoryName " +
                           "GROUP BY Categories.CategoryName");
```

Solution not in C#:

```
SELECT Categories.CategoryName ,
       SUM( SUBQUERY.TransactionCredit ) as CreditSum ,
       SUM( SUBQUERY.TransactionDebit  ) as DebitSum  ,
       SUM( SUBQUERY.TransactionCredit ) -
       SUM( SUBQUERY.TransactionDebit  ) as Difference ,
       SUM( SUBQUERY.TransactionDebit  ) /
       ( SELECT SUM(TransactionDebit)
         FROM Transactions
         WHERE AccountID = {currentAccountId}
       ) as 'Percent of Total Debit'
FROM Categories
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT CategoryName, 
           TransactionCredit, 
           TransactionDebit 
    FROM Transactions 
    WHERE AccountID = {currentAccountID}
      AND TransactionDate >= {startDate}
      AND TransactionDate <= {endDate}
) as SUBQUERY 
ON Categories.CategoryName = SUBQUERY.CategoryName
GROUP BY Categories.CategoryName
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query would be easier to following without the double quotes.  In any case, the problem is that the `where` clause refers to the `Transactions` table, undoing the `left outer join`.  Move those conditions into the `on` clause.  In your case, this is most easily done by changing the `where` to `and`:

```
"SELECT Categories.CategoryName, " +
"SUM(Transactions.TransactionCredit) as CreditSum, " +
"SUM(Transactions.TransactionDebit) as DebitSum, " +
"SUM(Transactions.TransactionCredit) - SUM(Transactions.TransactionDebit) as Difference, " +
"SUM(Transactions.TransactionDebit) / (SELECT SUM(TransactionDebit) FROM Transactions WHERE AccountID = " + currentAccountID + ") as 'Percent of Total Debit' " +
"FROM Categories LEFT JOIN Transactions on Categories.CategoryName = Transactions.CategoryName " +
"and Transactions.AccountID = " + currentAccountID +
(enableDateFilter? " AND TransactionDate >= #" + startDate + "# AND TransactionDate <= #" + endDate + "# " : " ") +
"GROUP BY Categories.CategoryName"
```

Comment: I apologize for that.  I have to write it this way in C# so I just copy and pasted it. But what you said results in the error "JOIN expression not supported

Comment: @Flappy . . . The reason for that was the `left outer join`, which MS Access calls `left join`.

Comment: I changed it to left join and that still didn't fix the issue.  Although Nicholas reformatted my question so the query is easier to read now.

Comment: Also, that can't be the reason because the Query works perfectly fine if I leave the WHERE in it.  If I change it to AND I get the error `JOIN expression not supported`

Answer (score 0):

As you're using a `LEFT JOIN` between `Categories` and `Transactions`, you should expect `NULL` values on Transaction table. Including your AccountID filter on JOIN clause will do the trick:

```
DECLARE @currentAccountId INT
SELECT  @currentAccountId = 1

;WITH   Transactions AS
(
    SELECT  *
    FROM    (   
    VALUES
                (1, 1000., 2000., 'Category B'),
                (2, 2000., 1000., 'Category B'),
                (1, 1000., 1000., 'Category C')
            )
            T ( AccountID, TransactionCredit, TransactionDebit, CategoryName)
),      Categories AS
(
    SELECT  *
    FROM    (
    VALUES
                ('Category A'),
                ('Category B'),
                ('Category C')
            )
            C (CategoryName)
)
SELECT      Categories.CategoryName ,
            SUM( Transactions.TransactionCredit ) as CreditSum ,
            SUM( Transactions.TransactionDebit  ) as DebitSum  ,
            SUM( Transactions.TransactionCredit ) -
            SUM( Transactions.TransactionDebit  ) as Difference ,
            SUM( Transactions.TransactionDebit  ) /
            (
                SELECT  SUM(TransactionDebit)
                FROM    Transactions
                WHERE   AccountID = @currentAccountId
            ) AS 'Percent of Total Debit'
FROM        Categories
LEFT JOIN   Transactions
    ON      Categories.CategoryName = Transactions.CategoryName
            AND Transactions.AccountID = @currentAccountId
            --AND TransactionDate >= {startDate}
            --AND TransactionDate <= {endDate}
GROUP BY    Categories.CategoryName
```

Results

```
CategoryName    CreditSum   DebitSum    Difference  Percent of Total Debit
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Category A      NULL        NULL        NULL        NULL
Category B      1000        2000        -1000       0.666666
Category C      1000        1000        0           0.333333
```

Comment: Ok but @Rubens this method does NOT work as I stated in Gordon's post.  I get the error `JOIN expression not supported` when I included multiple conditions for the LEFT JOIN.  If I change the first AND to a WHERE the query works fine but does not produce the intended results.